# How Can I Suggest next databases name when i create new database

Tags: mysql

1. Show databases;

| Database |
| --- |
| tenant_1 |
| tenant_2 |
| tenant_3 |
| tenant_4 |

When I want to create a new database it will suggest: tenant_5
2.Next database name suggestion tenant_5

Is there any way to do like this ?

I have not found any doc.

Comment: There is no feature in MySQL to do this automatically. You need to write code to query the current greatest schema name, then format a new schema name to be the next one. In other words, you will write code to do it in whatever your favorite language is.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need to do this rather than just putting it all in one database?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of existing user databases in your server with

```sql
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME
  FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
 WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN 
    ('mysql', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'sys')
 ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME;
```

Once you know the names of the databases already present, you can come up with another one using whatever algorithm you like.

But, consider this: what if your app proves successful and you find yourself with 500 new customers a day?  In that case you will be **really sorry** if you have to create a new database and new tables for each new customer.